# I have an ORA-06533 error in a select clausule

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to do a select and I get an ORA-06533 subcript beyond count.
I don't understand why is this error because there are no subscripts in the select.

I post the relevant code:

```
TYPE Item IS RECORD (
    entity number,
    period number,
    value NUMBER);
    TYPE ItemSet IS TABLE OF Item;

    modelo_pd ItemSet;

    select id_scenario into sid from sae_lc_scen_var where us_type = num and type = 0 and id_segment = pid;
    str := 'select distinct bd.entity_id, v.period_id, v.number_attribute_46 pd_pit
        from sae_scenario s, sae_baseline b, sae_baseline_data bd, sae_entity e, v_sae_scenario_data v
        where s.id = ' || sid || ' and b.scenario_type = s.scenario_type and b.id = bd.baseline_id 
        and bd.entity_id = e.id and b.id = s.baseline_id and v.scenario_id = s.id and v.baseline_id = b.id
        and e.string_attribute_1 = ''' || t.name || ''' and v.e_string_attribute_1 = e.string_attribute_1';
    execute immediate str bulk collect into modelo_pd;
```

The parameters for the query are from two other queries:

```
    select id_scenario into sid from sae_lc_scen_var where us_type = num and type = 0 and id_segment = pid;
```

and the loop:

```
for t in (select v.id_segment, s.name, v.value expert, v.value3 selection, v.value2 correction from sae_lc_scen_var v, sae_lc_segments s 
        where v.us_type = 1 and v.type = 0
        and s.id = v.id_segment and v.value <> 0)
```

The error raises in the dynamic select. That is in `execute immediate str bulk collect into modelo_pd;`
Any clue?

The full thing:

```
    num := get_constant('US_TYPE_EAD_AGGREGATE');
    for t in (select v.id_segment, s.name, v.value expert, v.value3 selection, v.value2 correction from sae_lc_scen_var v, sae_lc_segments s 
        where v.us_type = 1 and v.type = 0
        and s.id = v.id_segment and v.value <> 0)
    loop
        -- value3: 0=Model, 1=Proxy VMG, 2=Expert, 3=PD_TTC
        num := get_constant('US_TYPE_LGD_CALC_METHOD');

        if t.selection = 0 then
            num := get_constant('US_TYPE_MODELOS_PD');
            select id_scenario into sid from sae_lc_scen_var where us_type = num and type = 0 and id_segment = pid;
            str := 'select distinct bd.entity_id, v.period_id, v.number_attribute_46 pd_pit
                    from sae_scenario s, sae_baseline b, sae_baseline_data bd, sae_entity e, v_sae_scenario_data v
                    where s.id = ' || sid || ' and b.scenario_type = s.scenario_type and b.id = bd.baseline_id 
                    and bd.entity_id = e.id and b.id = s.baseline_id and v.scenario_id = s.id and v.baseline_id = b.id
                    and e.string_attribute_1 = ''' || t.name || ''' and v.e_string_attribute_1 = e.string_attribute_1';
            execute immediate str bulk collect into modelo_pd;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the error.
There is no rows for that select so when I use `modelo_pd` it gives that error.

What is unclear for me is why it is giving the line number way before the subscript is used.

Comment: Minor comment, you should prefer **ANSI Join Syntax** and better use `where s.id = :sid and ... and e.string_attribute_1 = :name and ...` and then `execute immediate str bulk collect into modelo_pd USING SID, t.name;`

Comment: Thank you so much for the lesson.